# Does the Yosemite (OSX 10.10) feature of xcode live views work with NSView on OSX?

Tags: xcode, macos, nsview

I'm trying to determine if the live view feature works with NSView on OSX 10.10, or is it only iOS at the moment?

It works great with UIView for iOS projects, however I haven't been able to get OSX projects to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does work. You just need to add the same symbols for IBDesignable (before the class interface declaration) and IBInspectable (before the property you want to edit in IB) in the right places in you view class header and be sure your nib or storyboard has the class set properly in tge inspector in IB.

You also need to note that the must be properties and they are somewhat limited in type.

Sometimes IB is still a little flaky about recognizing it right away, so you might need to build or reopen the tab with that nib or storyboard.

Also I would expect your mileage may vary with subclasses of more complex views and remember this only works for objects that are descendants of NSView at some point. No NSCell descendants.

Comment: One more thing. It only works against the 10.10 SDK. anything earlier won't work.

Comment: Ok great! I think part of the problem was that for the OSX test project I was using swift, rather then Objective-C. That probably meant a few error got through.

Comment: Yeah... Not even sure. Swift is still kind of confusing to me. Objective-C works well, is well-established and I know it, so I've not yet spent much time in swift. Can't really help in swift yet.